# i wrote the code for fibonacci series but i get error ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException. can you please help me

Tags: java

I wrote the code for Fibonacci series but I get error `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException`. Can you please help me find source of this exception?

```
class Fib {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println("Fibonacci Series");
        int f1, f2 = 0, f3 = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + f3 + " ");
            f1 = f2;
            f2 = f3;
            f3 = f1 + f2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you get exception and you want to ask others about it, beside code which throws this exception post also its [stacktrace](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3988794/1393766).

Answer (score 4):

You didn't supply any command-line arguments to your program, so `args` is a zero-length array.  Any access of a zero-length array will result in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Check if `args.length` is at least `1` before accessing the first element (of index `0`).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the code you submitted but here is couple of clues:

- You are executing the application without any argument.
- You should first check if the arguments length is greater than 0.
- Before parsing the input argument, do either check if it is a number or surround the parsing with a try/catch.

I hope this helps.

Good luck!